# Actualizar registro al presionar un botón en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Mi problema es que no logro actualizar datos de los registros que tengo en mi base de datos usando Laravel. Lo que estoy haciendo es que al presionar un BUTTON, automáticamente se registre la hora actual, lo que quiero es que, al presionar por primera vez el BUTTON se registre la hora actual y que ésta se registre primero en la base de datos, y, cuando presione el BUTTON por segunda vez, se registre la hora actual en el cual se presiona el BUTTON por segunda vez, y que ésta se registre en una celda distinta junto con el registro de la hora actual que se registro cuando se presione el BUTTON por primera vez.

Hasta ahora ya logré registrar la hora actual al presionar el BUTTON por segunda vez, pero aún no cuando se presiona el BUTTON por segunda vez.

Espero se entienda, y gracias de antemano.

Acá dejo las partes de mi proyecto.

**(Modelo)**
**Registrar.php**

```
class Registrar extends Model
    {
        //
    public $timestamps = false;
        protected $table = 'registro';


    }
```

**(Controlador)**
**RegistrarController.php**

```
$hora = date("H:i:s");
$asistencia -> hora_ingreso = $hora;
```

**(Vista)**
**Registrar.blade.php**

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/actualizar" role="form">

            <div class="botones" style='margin-left: 10px'>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="registrar" value="Registrar Ingreso" id="btn_registrar"> </div>

            </form>
```

**MostrarDatos.blade.php**

```
<td>{{$asistencia->hora_ingreso}}</td>
```

**Rutas:**

```
Route::post('/actualizar','RegistrarController@insertar');
```

Comment: Toma en cuenta que laravel cuenta con los campos 
created_at
updated_at
deleted_at

Que por defecto ya realiza estás acciones.

Answer (score 0):

La lógica puede ser que si existe un registro previo lo actualizas, del contrario lo creas.

Te dejo un código para explicar el proceso, ya que el código provisto por ti no es suficiente para entregarte un controlador detallado.

```
$previous_record = Model::find($id); 
if(!$previous_record){
    $miclass = new MiClass();
    $miclass->miprop = time();
    $miclass->save();
}else{
    $previous_record->miprop = time();
    $previous_record->save();
}
```

Luego retornas la `ID` a tu vista y la agregas como `input` en el formulario para que el registro se actualice la próxima vez que el controlador procese la petición.

Comment: Existe una opción más simple y menos verbosa, te recomiendo buscar `updateOrCreate`

Answer (score -1):

Si todo lo quieres hacer desde una misma vista, haz una condición de que si ya existe un registro algo como:

```
@if ($asistencia->hora == null)
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/registrar" role="form">

            <div class="botones" style='margin-left: 10px'>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="registrar" value="Registrar Ingreso" id="btn_registrar"> </div>

            </form>
@else
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/actualizar" role="form">

            <div class="botones" style='margin-left: 10px'>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="registrar" value="Registrar Ingreso" id="btn_registrar"> </div>

            </form>
@endif
```

algo asi